# Can I filter by apiVersion in kubectl?

Tags: kubectl

I want to find all the kubernetes ingresses that are still `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`, because I'm upgraded my kubernetes cluster (EKS) from 1.21 to 1.22 and we should be using `networking.k8s.io/v1` instead.

I tried

```
kubectl  get ingress --all-namespaces --field-selector apiVersion="networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 "
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses" that match label selector "", field selector "apiVersion=networking.k8s.io/v1beta1": "apiVersion" is not a known field selector: only "metadata.name", "metadata.namespace"
```

Is there a way to nicely filter by `apiVersion` in kubectl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `go-template` to avoid piping to other tools like `jq`:

```
kubectl get ingress  -A -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{if (eq .apiVersion "networking.k8s.io/v1")}}{{ .metadata.name }}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

In a bit more readable format:

```
kubectl get ingress  -A -o go-template='{{range .items}}
                                          {{- if (eq .apiVersion "networking.k8s.io/v1") -}}
                                            {{ .metadata.name }}{{"\n"}}
                                          {{- end -}}
                                       {{end}}'
```

Comment: does the filtering happen at the client side or server side? I assume it's client side , right?

Comment: Yes. Client side.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround is to request all ingresses as JSON and filter that locally using `jq`

```
kubectl  get ingress --all-namespaces -o json > result.json
cat result.json |  jq '.items[]|select(.apiVersion=="networking.k8s.io/v1beta1")|[.apiVersion,.metadata.name, .metadata.namespace]'
```

will produce

```
[
  "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "rubelagu-helloworld",
  "hello-world"
], 
[
  "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "rubelagu-helloworld",
  "hello-world2"
]
```